# load a json file containing list of strings

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a json file containing a list of strings like this:

```
['Hello\nHow are you?', 'What is your name?\nMy name is john']
```

I have to read this file and store it as a list of strings but I am so confused that how should I read json file like this. Also, I should use utf-8 encoding format.

Comment: You example "json file" is not valid JSON.  Valid JSON would look like `["Hello\\nHow are you?", "What is your name?\\nMy name is john"]`.  Is that really what's in the file itself?

Comment: I don't think this is valid json file!

Comment: @MarkTolonen link to the file has been added

Comment: @Masoud Paste a sample text from the file itself. Questions should be self-contained without links and preferably without images unless it is the only way to convey the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have one or multiple lines as described in the `json` file. Here is my suggestion (Remember to replace the file name `test.json` to yours):

```
import ast

with open("test.json", "r") as input_file:
    line_list = input_file.readlines()

all_texts = [item for sublist in line_list for item in ast.literal_eval(sublist)]
print(all_texts)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I just first opened the file and then I used literal_eval and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The file you have shown is not in json format. Anyways, to read a json file you have to do following

import json

```
jsonObj = json.loads('path/to/file.json')
```

This will return a dictionary object and store it in jsonObj.

Comment: I do this but I get 'JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)' error

Comment: I dont quite understand what is written in the file. But from the looks of it, it doesn't look like its a json format and thats the reason for JSONDecodeError.